# Akka Http caching metrics

Tags: scala, caching, akka, metrics

I'm using Akka HTTP caching and I would love to add some metrics like cache hit/miss to understand how's my cache doing.

I'm reading [this documentation on Akka HTTP Caching](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/common/caching.html). However I'm not seeing anywhere if their cache supports metrics.

I'm using the `getOrLoad` [method](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka-http/10.2.6/akka/http/caching/scaladsl/Cache.html#getOrLoad(key:K,loadValue:K=%3Escala.concurrent.Future%5BV%5D):scala.concurrent.Future%5BV%5D). Am I missing something or it's just the fact that they don't do any metrics for this library?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see anything in Akka documentation either but if you are using the Caffeine implementation you could maybe have access to Caffeine methods and enable statistics.

Caffeine statistics documentation: https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/wiki/Statistics

*Obviously, you would not anymore be agnostic of the caching library.*